# How do I find the correct source code based on msi revision number?

Tags: windows-installer, tortoisesvn

When I right-click on a Windows Installer Package, I can see a revision number,i.e. {F8403FD4-463C-41B5-BAB4-CD18C1E10B7A}

This doesnt seem to bear any relationship to either the TortoiseSVN Revision numbers, which look like 16299, ad they don't look like Versions, which look like 2.33.0.0.

It is important that I debug this code and repair it using the correct version.

How do they relate? how cani get the correct source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what tool you are using to author your MSI in but most tools generate a random GUID for "PackageCode" (aka Summary Information Stream Revision ) at build time.  The only time this would be true is an edge case situations to support build reproducibility and maybe some weird patching situation.

Typically a build system would have to version the MSI (ProductVersion property) and label the source to make the connection you are looking for.  You could also watermark the MSI with the source control version number.

You could then use Orca to look at an MSI for it's watermark, ProductVersion property or FileVersions of files in the File table to trace it back to the original build.  From there you would rely on that build having a label or log of some sort to get branch and version used.

Comment: I am working backwards here.A fault has been reported on an existing installation. It is the code behind that I need to get my hands on. What I may or may not be able to do in the future is not relevant to me here. Package would have been created using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Did you happen to version the files that went into the install?

Comment: I didn't do the install,and can't get hold of the person who did, as they have left the company. All our software is versioned.

Comment: You can extract the MSI or examine it using ORCA to get the version #'s for your EXE/DLL files.  Then use that to figure out what build it was.  Hopefully your builds are labling source otherwise use the date time of the build and branch information to work it out.

Comment: msiexec /a FOO.MSI TARGETDIR=C:\EXTRACT

Comment: "msiexec /a FOO.MSI TARGETDIR=C:\EXTRACT" - what is this supposed to do? this gave me version number of Windows Installer?

Comment: It extracts the files from your MSI to C:\EXTRACT.  Then you can go look at your EXE/DLL to get the version number.

Comment: "msiexec /a FOO.MSI TARGETDIR=C:\EXTRACT" did nothing. C;/EXTRACT is empty after executing.

Comment: Did you type foo.msi or the filename of your msi?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86708/discussion-between-christopher-painter-and-steve-staple).